# SVG transform: translate(-50% -50%) works differently in Chromium/Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am currently appending a number of `foreignObject`s to an SVG and noticed that when applying transform: translate(-50% -50%) that in Chromium this means "-50% of the width and height of the object", but in Chrome/Firefox/Edge it means "-50% of the offset to window".

I'm not sure which is right or wrong, but the desired functionality is Chromium's logic. How could I apply this to all the other browsers? The rendered object is:

```
<foreignObject id="bubble7" data-id="7" 
    x="1502.0229174501765" y="496.93078252741776" width="200" height="41" fill="black" 
    style="transform: translate(-50%,-50%)">
    <textarea class="bubble place" style="height: 40px;">Some text</textarea>
</foreignObject>
```

Please see the following jsfiddle, which pushes the translate box to the top left in chrome but works fine in edge: https://jsfiddle.net/c52bmxs9/6/

Comment: @niemaszoka I could be wrong, I'm just trying to find out the right way to have the translate apply to width/height. When I remove the translate, the object returns to page center

Comment: Can you please provide w JSfiddle  that shows your problem?

Comment: Why do you use `transform` when you can set `x` and `y` directly?

Comment: @niemaszoka https://jsfiddle.net/c52bmxs9/6/

Comment: @CBauer Asking which browser is right and which browser is wrong is rather pointless. If you look at the spec on the [`transform`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) attribute you will find that percentage values are not allowed for this attribute. Basing your graphic on unspecified behaviour leaves it vulnerable to future change which might happen without notice. I suggest you rethink your approach and try to achieve what you want by some other means. You may want to rephrase your question or ask a new one if you need help with the implementation.

Comment: Thanks @altocumulus, do you want to post this as the answer so I can accept it? I think this would be a valid question/answer for others in the future (unless the same answer has been discovered elsewhere).

Comment: @CBauer Alright, will do so. It‘s going to take some time, though, since right now I am on my mobile.